# Data has disappeared from OneNote on a Sharepoint Online Team site

Tags: sharepoint-online, onenote

How does one restore a OneNote from a previous date prior to the missing data?

Answer (score 1):

Onenote maintains its own version history and sync mechanism. You can open the onenote and navigate to the history tab to view all changes. See this [support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/see-a-list-of-recent-changes-in-a-notebook-in-onenote-for-windows-55dc5183-9112-4c7e-a9cf-44cd66c19c77) for more information.